# Issue Migrating magento from XAMPP to live server

Tags: magento, xampp, localhost, hosting

I attempted to migrate my magento store to a live server today and it does not appear to be working correctly

http://66preview.co.uk/synthmusic/

the page content and menu bar have disappeared along with a few other issues

I changed the local.xml to the live DB settings and changed the core config table in the DB to the correct url path, Im I missing something else?

Im totally stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check the log files var/log/  and let me know the content

Comment: Hi there, thank you for quick response :) I do not have a log folder, under var is cache, locks, package, report and session.

Comment: is there any file in report  folder ?

Comment: share the content of last file

Comment: There actually isnt any more report files since I put on the live server, the last one was

      a:4:{i:0;s:94:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'democom_demo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2712:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\synth-music\synthmusic\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

Answer (score 1):

You have upload your local database? and you need to truncate your url rewrite table and clear your cache.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) how do I truncate the url rewrite table?

Comment: from admin panel you can also remove all entry from catalog->url rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Points to check:

```
1) Have you used static urls in the code?
2) Check for capitalization because Linux is case sensitive.
3) Check for the directory separators, these should be / for Linux.
```

There may be other issues if you can post error or specific message.That will be more helpfull.

Comment: Hi there :) where abouts would I look to se if they were static urls? sorry if thtas a dumb question, I was just given the site to edit about of css and it worked fine when I put it on xampp

Comment: @Shaddai Do you mean to say that you did some css changes after moving the existing site to xampp?